# Wireless connection not working BCM4318

Tags: drivers

The wireless card in the Acer 3000 is Broad com BCM4318
PCL-ID 14e4:4318

supported 
yes
Chip ID Bcm4318

modes a/b/g

phy version G

I am new user and typed in sudo apt-get install-b43 fwcutter firmware -b43-installer.
The wireless card is recognized by computer and I can select the home network in settings but nothing activates to apply settings and connect wireless. Running Kubuntu 18.04
Have no idea how to proceed.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of these terminal commands: `rfkill list all` and also: `nmcli dev wifi list`  Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score -1):

Driver was installed.  Go to settings and open connectivity. At bottom click on add. Click on wireless. Screen pops up where you answer question about wireless connection.  did not know what I was doing but got the right combination. had to go to top left of screen and clicked on un boarder. this allowed me to see place where you input security code and the save was active and hit that. Wirless was not active.the whole process was more luck than anything